When I use FindIndex() it returns -1 in c#?
I'm trying to build a simple program that sorts numbers from biggest to smallest with arrays in c#.
//basic number sorter. every number should be on one line and separated by a " " (space).
int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
int[] bigToSmall = new int[numbers.Length];
int biggestNum = int.MinValue;
for (int y = 0; y < numbers.Length; y++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > biggestNum)
        {
            biggestNum = numbers[i];
        }
        else if (numbers[i] == biggestNum)
        {
            numbers[i] = biggestNum;
        }
    }
    var bigIndx = Array.FindIndex(numbers, row => row == biggestNum);
    numbers[bigIndx] = 0;
    bigToSmall[y] = biggestNum;
}
for (int i = 0; i < bigToSmall.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bigToSmall[i]);
}

When I run the program I get: "Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."
Here are also the values I get when I use the input "1 2 3"
I have tried to use also IndexOf,but it didnt work. Any ideas why it doesn't work, and how I can fix it?

The else...if doesn't make sense, you replace the number with itself. Btw, why you can't use int[] bigToSmall=numbers.OrtderByDescending(i=>i).ToArray()?

Sounds like you need to debug your code. You should write out the algorithm that you're trying to implement, then step through the code and compare its behaviour to a manual implementation of the algorithm. I suspect that you will find that what the code does not match the algorithm at at least one point, so that would be your issue. If the code does match the algorithm but still doesn't produce the expected result then it's the algorithm that is faulty, so you need to go back to that stage and look at your logic and the algorithm, which doesn't involve code at all.

Sorting is a big topic and unless using readymade methods like Array.Sort, List<T>.Sort, linq OrderBy, etc. you are better to decide first on an algorithm you are trying to implement and sticking to its pseudo-code as close as you can. E.g. bubble sort.

var bigToSmall = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).OrderByDescending(item => item).ToArray();

It will be the second iteration through the y loop. You haven't reset biggestNum back to minvalue so it will be looking for the one you removed last time.
